# Changes on php code Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone help me custom php code .

http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/en/home-page/

In english version in right top corner i have login "zaloguj" button but i can't change name for english version to [login].

This is code in php for it

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo '<a href="'.wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Wyloguj" class="zaloguj">Wyloguj</a>'; } else { echo '<a href="/zaloguj" title="Zaloguj" class="zaloguj">Zaloguj</a>'; } ?>
```

Thanks for your answers
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick fix use `get_locale()` to check current language and set the text:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) .'" title="Wyloguj" class="zaloguj">'
            . 'Wyloguj'
            . '</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="/zaloguj" title="Zaloguj" class="zaloguj">' 
            . ( ( get_locale() === 'pl_PL' ) ? 'Wyloguj' : 'Login' )
            . '</a>';
}
?>
```

Better would be using internationalization (i18n) by using the `__($text)` function. The text will be translated if there's a translation available. WP has a built-in translation for "Log in" and "Log out". This means when using `__('Log in')` or `__('Log out')`, it will be automatically translated to the current site language.

Using `__()` will look like:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) .'" title="'. __('Log out') .'" class="zaloguj">' 
            . __('Log out') 
            . '</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="/zaloguj" title="'. __('Log in') .'" class="zaloguj">'
            . __('Log in') 
            . '</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: It almost work fine But.

In Pl language i have correct "zaloguj" when i log in still have "zaloguj" which means log in . 
In En i got Log in correct but when i log out i got "wygoluj " 

I have polylang translation and in settings is no string for log or log out .
This secend php code if i past will be work?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. The second code should work. I've tested it.

Comment: Look . I have site with 2 languages Polish and English . i have plugin Theme my login which show [Login/Logout] form and button . In polish version is all good . But when i change to english plugin dosent trasnlate it . All i want is to make in english version of my site Login/Logout button name .

http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/en/home-page/

Right top corner button is

Answer (score 0):

Just change and it says login

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo '<a href="'.wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Wyloguj" class="zaloguj">Wyloguj</a>'; } else { echo '<a href="/zaloguj" title="Zaloguj" class="zaloguj">Login</a>'; } ?>
```

That said much better option is to use l18n plugin to make proper internalisation for the page.

More details here. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Comment: I have two language site , and have this code for 2 languages . What i want to achive is to have in polish version [Zaloguj] and english [Login]
But have only this one code if i change it like you say in polish version will be[login]

Comment: That is why you should use internalisation instead of editing the code directly

Comment: OK , i not a expert in php . I looking for easier to me fix . I look what you send me , but i dont think i can handle with it.